# jq value remove everything before first space

Tags: json, string, jq

Could you help me please?

I got a json of a format similar to this:

```
{"key":"this.part:2 and now comes the rest"}
```

How can I use jq only style to remove everything before the first space meaning this part: `this.part:2`?

I tried already `jq '.key |= sub(".* "; "")'` but that didn't unfortunately do what I wanted to have.
Can anybody help please?

Comment: So, you want the output to be, `{"key": "and now comes the rest"}`?

Comment: correct, but I think the question has been answered already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`sub`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#sub%28regex%3Btostring%29%2Csub%28regex%3Btostring%3Bflags%29) with a regex, `.*` will greedily match as much as it can, so the following space character is satisfied with the last ocurrence of it. Make `*` lazy by appending a `?` to have it stop before the first occurrence:

```bash
.key |= sub(".*? "; "")
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/dpil6RQy1-M)

Or, more explicitly, replace everything from the beginning `^`, followed by any number of non-space characters `[^ ]*`, and the space itself:

```bash
.key |= sub("^[^ ]* "; "")
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/lv7-V1mzkBv)

Or use [`index`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#index%28s%29%2Crindex%28s%29) to get the position of the first space character, then get the substring starting one position after that index using `.[<n>:]`:

```bash
.key |= .[index(" ")+1:]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/EVp10eD_Mby)

Both produce:

```json
{
  "key": "and now comes the rest"
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the last post very helpful. A lot appreciated.